# Absolute position with table-layout: fixed takes up space

Tags: html, css

I have a fake table (divs rendered as a table).
There is only one row with 6 cells. The last one of them i set to position: absolute, and the table is set to table-layout: fixed.
Now the plan is to have the 5 first cells take up 20% each and the last one taking up no space. (as it needs to be moved outside of the box).

For some reason the table-layout: fixed also counts in the cell with position absolute meaning that each cell is given around 16% each.

The thing is that I need to be able to use the same css if the table all the sudden goes to 10 (+1) etc.

I have made a fiddle showing off the issue here.
https://jsfiddle.net/nxy0d023/

This is my css (simplified)

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.table div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 10px;
}

.table .last {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

It is possible that I set each cell to a size if needed but that does not work sadly.

Comment: Why do you need this element to be inside the table element to begin with?

Comment: I'm in agreement why! can you show us a diagram or explain what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I dont have an image to show, but let me explain. I am making a custom bar chart (horizontal) using html. Below it is a range from 0% to 100% in increments of either 10 or 20. For Increments of 20 I split it up into 5 equal pieces with a label to the very left. For the last one (100%) i place it manually using position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `width: 100%` to the `.table div`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxy0d023/1/)

Comment: Very clever solution and seems to work in FF as well.

Comment: @Resin01 Maybe you can avoid this DOM structure to begin with, and put the last `div` outside of the `table` div

Comment: I have been thinking about that but it would make my code to set it up quite ugly. If no other solution is found, I might fall back to that.

Comment: I ended up setting the with manually by calculating the width from the count, and then changing eveything to inline-blocks. Works like a charm in all browsers.